# Kubernetes request to service timeout value

Tags: networking, kubernetes, flannel, kubespray

We are using Kubernetes `v1.9.5` on bare metal, deployed with `kubespray`, network driver - `flannel`.

When doing HTTP request from pod to another service, if that service has no endpoint, request hangs for **exactly 130 seconds** (I checked in via `NodeJS` net library and via `curl`).

Where this value comes from?

We noticed in while writing retries that try to establish connection to service.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the iptables will DROP packet if its destined to a non-existent end-point and DROP will never send a message back to the requester ([DROP/REJECT](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject)) . This will result in retires from requester.
Retries depends on the parameter `net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries` and by default its 6 in CentOS-7

When I set `net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=1` in the minion where the requester pod runs , the timeout happens in 3 seconds instead of the 2m 7.23s

I hope this clarifies why curl or any port connect request hangs for long time if the request is for a non-existent endpoint.